# How to retrieve the calendar of a meeting room through Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I want to retrieve the calendar of a meeting room.

In order to do that I am using the following method

https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/meetingroom@mailadress.com/calendarview?endDateTime=2018-02-13T11:06:03&startDateTime=2018-02-12T11:06:03.

However I am getting this error:

```
{
 "error": {
    "code": "ErrorItemNotFound",
    "message": "The specified object was not found in the store.",
    "innerError": {
        "request-id": "e3401a80-6d31-4ae3-81d3-7a0b43eb7766",
        "date": "2018-02-10T11:16:14"
    }
 }
}
```

I am using the Microsoft Graph Explorer where I have configured the following permissions :

```
- Calendars.Read
- Calendars.Read.Shared 
- Calendars.ReadWrite 
- Calendars.ReadWrite.Shared
```

I have no issue accessing the calendar of the meeting room through outlook application. What did I miss ?

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: No I still have the same issue :(

Comment: Any updates here? Did any one get it to work?

Comment: I have still the same issue. I don't know if it worked for others.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ErrorItemNotFound when trying to retrieve room calendar via MS Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53739394/erroritemnotfound-when-trying-to-retrieve-room-calendar-via-ms-graph-api)

Comment: Seems to be a permissions issue. See the answers on this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53739394/erroritemnotfound-when-trying-to-retrieve-room-calendar-via-ms-graph-api

Comment: This just isn’t possible, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/54208225/639153